# How to change the order of function's argumnets

Tags: python

*edited

What I want to is as below

```
def func(x1, x2, ... , xi, ..., xn):
   doing something
   return

def F(func, i):
   def newFunc(xi, x2, ..., x1, ..., xn):
      return func(x1, x2, ..., xi, ..., xn)
   doing something with newFunc
```

where n is unknown(arbitrary)
*

I am not good at English and I am a beginner of python, so please understand. 
I make a function that takes a function and an integer.
Let me call the function what I make as `F`, the function that is an argument of `F` as `func`, and the integer as `i`.
In the `F`, a new function which first argument and `i`-th argument of `func` are switched is made. (I'll do something with the new function in `F`.)
If I exactly know the arguments of `func`, I can make the `F` as below.
But If I don't know the number of arguments, how can I make `F`?

```
def F(func, i=1):
    def newFunc(u, x, e):
        return func(x, u, e)

    ...Do something with newFunction...
```

I tried `signature`, but the return of `signature` can't be switched.
And I tried `.__code__.co_varnames` as below

```
def F(func, i):
    arg_num = func.__code__.co_argcount
    arg_pre = list(func.__code__.co_varnames)[:arg_num]
    arg_next = list(func.__code__.co_varnames)[:arg_num]
    arg_next[0], arg_next[i] = arg_next[i], arg_next[0]
    def newFunc(arg_next):
        return func(arg_pre)
```

In this case, however, `return func(arg_pre)` recognizes `arg_pre` as 1 positional argument.

I hope you understand what I want to mean. Thank you.

Comment: `
def F(func, i):
    def new_fun(*argument):
        argument = list(argument)
        argument[0], argument[i] = argument[i], argument[0]
        return func(*argument)
`
This works to me.

Answer (score 1):

`newFunc` can accept an *arbitrary* number of arguments, although this means `F` cannot verify that there really *is* an `i`th argument when you call the return value of `F`.

```
def F(func, i=1):
    def newFunc(*args):
        x = args[0]
        y = args[i]
        return func(y, *args[1:i], x, *args[i+1:])
    return newFunc
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your answer gave me some intuition. I figured the problem out.